# Scalar field theory in global AdS vs Poincare

Tags: quantum-field-theory, ads-cft

If I solve the Klein Gordon equation in the Poincare patch with the boundary condition that the field vanishes at infinity I get a continuous set of solutions.These are normalizable solutions and I can quantize scalar field theory on Poincare patch. I then have a continuously infinite basis.

On the other hand if I solve the Klein Gordon equation in global AdS I have to used boundary conditions as well as regularity at the origin, and then I have a countably infinite set of solutions. I quantize to obtain a countably infinite basis.

My questions is, why this difference? Are all the solutions in the Poincare chart no longer solutions when expressed in terms of global coordinates? And how is it consistent that the quantum theory on AdS can have either a continuously infinite normalizable basis (Poincare) or a countably infinite normalizable basis (global chart)?

Comment: Presumably when you cover the entirety of AdS with Poincare patches you find that those solutions which are consistent with the patching are the countably infinite ones you find in global coordinates?

Comment: I would think so, but that would mean that if I did quantum field theory in Poincare patch and in Anti de Sitter, the two would not be connected via Bogoliubov transformations.

Comment: Yes, that would be what you expect. Boundary conditions change the problem

Comment: Seems odd that for example two point functions are the same whichever modes are used.